# beginner [python] How to get attribute of of a child element and text of its subchild?

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, parsing

I would like for each `ver` who have the attribute 'fmc' to get the text inside the tag `part`.

so for my example just to return  two ver (30 & 54)

the first loop print nothing. I need help to improve the function I am writing.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3


import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree= ET.parse(r'test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


for ver in root.iter('ver'):
    if ver.attrib == 'fmc':
        print(ver.attrib) # does not work
        for elem in root.iter():
            if elem.tag == 'part':
                print(elem.text)
```

file

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<corpus>
    <ver id="18" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="1" critere="1.3" type="discours">
        <part code="EC1_Elec_IW04_0">Ça existe sur des gros parcs Hlm mais c'est macro.</part>
    </ver>
    <ver id="30" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="2" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours" fmc="motivation">
        <part code="EC1_Elec_IW01_0">Avant 75 on n'a pas isolé puis après, au fur et à mesure des règlementations.</part>
    </ver>
    <ver id="54" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="1" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours" fmc="condition">
        <part code="EC1_Elec_IW10_0">Le deuxième boitier, il est où ? s'il y en a un qui est à l'intérieur et qui remplace un bout de l'isolation, il est caché OK.</part>
    </ver>
    <ver id="897" etude="EC3_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="4" critere="4.1" origine="TR" type="discours">
        <part code="EC3_Elec_TR2_1">Avec l'économie d'énergie, on va imposer de plus en plus d'automatismes,</part>
        <iwer>Çava influencer la demande pour ce type de solution c'est ça ?</iwer>
        <part code="EC3_Elec_TR2_1">Je pense oui</part>
    </ver>
</corpus>
```

Comment: This code shouldn't run at all, since here: `tree = root = tree.getroot()` you're using `tree` **before** you assign anything to it.

Comment: when I pasted I made error I rewrite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ver.attrib
```

returns a dictionary.

Check for the key you are looking(i.e. fmc) and then print.

```
if ver.attrib.get('fmc', None):
```

Code :

```
for ver in root.iter('ver'):
    if ver.attrib.get('fmc', None):
        print(ver.attrib['fmc']) # it does work
        for elem in root.iter():
            if elem.tag == 'part':
                print(elem.text)
```

Complete code with errors fixed :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

arbre = ET.parse(r'abc.xml')
root = arbre.getroot()

for ver in root.iter('ver'):
    if ver.attrib.get('fmc', None):
        print(ver.attrib['fmc'])
        for elem in root.iter():
            if elem.tag == 'part':
                print(elem.text)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you is possible to rewrite it as function so that it will return value of ver.attrib and elem.text : for exemple :

Answer (score 2):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

xml = '''<corpus>
    <ver id="18" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="1" critere="1.3" type="discours">
        <part code="EC1_Elec_IW04_0">Ça existe sur des gros parcs Hlm mais c'est macro.</part>
    </ver>
    <ver id="30" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="2" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours" fmc="motivation">
        <part code="EC1_Elec_IW01_0">Avant 75 on n'a pas isolé puis après, au fur et à mesure des règlementations.</part>
    </ver>
    <ver id="54" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="1" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours" fmc="condition">
        <part code="EC1_Elec_IW10_0">Le deuxième boitier, il est où ? s'il y en a un qui est à l'intérieur et qui remplace un bout de l'isolation, il est caché OK.</part>
    </ver>
    <ver id="897" etude="EC3_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="4" critere="4.1" origine="TR" type="discours">
        <part code="EC3_Elec_TR2_1">Avec l'économie d'énergie, on va imposer de plus en plus d'automatismes,</part>
        <iwer>Çava influencer la demande pour ce type de solution c'est ça ?</iwer>
        <part code="EC3_Elec_TR2_1">Je pense oui</part>
    </ver>
</corpus>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
data = [{'fmc': ver.attrib.get('fmc'),'part': ver.find('./part').text} for ver in root.findall('.//ver') if ver.attrib.get('fmc')]
print(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head())
```

Comment: Thank you but I just want to print the part if the ver contains fmc; if it does not I do not nedd the part.

Comment: @kely789456123 The code was modified and in 1 line of code it will get you what you are looking for.

Comment: thank you but is there a way to use it in a function so that I will return the value and the text like in dataframe  : return fmc, value

Comment: @kely789456123 Not Sure I understand. Do you want to create a pandas dataframe from the list of fmc,part pairs? I have added pandas support to the code.

Comment: I wanted to be able to include that line ([{'fmc': ver.attrib.get('fmc'),'part': ver.find('./part').text} for ver in root.findall('.//ver') if ver.attrib.get('fmc')]
print(data))  in a function which will return two values  : the value of the attribute and the texT.